# I keep getting An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code for RetailPrice

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

```
protected void btnCalculateOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OrderSession();

    if (IsValid)
    {
        double RetailPrice = Convert.ToDouble(lblRetailPrice);
        double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity);
        double Tax = (.9);

        double Subtotal = RetailPrice * Quantity;
        double TotalAmount = Subtotal + Tax;

        lblSubTotal.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
        lblTotalAmount.Text = TotalAmount.ToString("c");
    }

}
```

Comment: did you debug it and what is the value in lblRetailPrice ?

Comment: Yes and debugging only picks it up once i use the button. The lblRetailPrice is predetermined in a database given through a drop down list. But its a label

Comment: `lblSubTotal.Text = Subtotal.ToString("c");
lblTotalAmount.Text = TotalAmount.ToString("c");` `ToString` should be `ToString("C")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nitpicking, you do not need the bracket:

```
double Tax = (.9); //change to double Tax = .9; or double Tax = 0.9;
```

Problem:

Seems like you want to `Convert` the `Controls` rather than the `Text` of the `Controls`

```
double RetailPrice = Convert.ToDouble(lblRetailPrice); //I assume this is a Label Control
double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity); //and this is a TextBox Control
```

Try to change them to:

```
double RetailPrice = Convert.ToDouble(lblRetailPrice.Text);
double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(txtQuantity.Text);
```

Comment: @CurtisCrossman what are you working with? `WinForms`? Also, please check what is the `lblRetailPrice` and the `txtQuantity` are they `Label` and `TextBox` `Controls` respectively? If not, what are they?

Comment: Yes im using Webforms and yes there labels and textboxes

Comment: @CurtisCrossman OK `WebForms`, not `WinForms`. In that case, what is the `.Text` input for both `Controls`? If they are not in the correct format, they cannot be processed. `double` expects format like `1.234`. What are the `Texts`?

Comment: The text is like $1.23

Comment: @CurtisCrossman that *is* the reason! ;) you don't want the `$` take that out using `Substring`

Comment: Perfect! So how can i display the $ with a tostring"c"?

Comment: Yes, ToString("C") will display number as a local currency number. ;)